# Nested list with TAL

Tags: pyramid, markup, chameleon, tal

I'm using Chameleon in the Pyramids Framework and want to repeat nested list while rendering the template.

My minimized HTML-Code is:

```
1. <ul>
2.  <li tal:repeat="item items">
3.      <input tal:attributes="id item.id; onclick item.url">
4.      <label tal:repeat="premise item.values" tal:attributes="for item.id; id premise.id">
5.          <label tal:replace="premise.title"/>
6.      </label>
7.      <label tal:attributes="for item.id" tal:content="item.title"/>
8.  </li>
9. </ul>
```

Whereby I got the following json-Data

```
[{
    'url': 'location.href="http://..."',
    'values':
    [{
        'id': '70',
        'title': 'some title 1'
    }],
    'attitude': 'justify', 
    'id': '68',
    'title': 'some title 2'
}, {
    'url': 'null',
    'values':
    [{
        'id': '0',
        'title': 'some title 3!
    }],
    'attitude': 'justify',
    'id': '0',
    'title':
    'some title 4'
}]
```

If I kill HTML-lines 4.-6., everything is fine, otherwise Pyramid/Chameleon throws:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/chameleon/tal.py", line 471, in __call__
    iterable = list(iterable) if iterable is not None else ()
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Anyone some idea?

Comment: Okay, I've tried tal:repeat="premise item.values()" in line 4., but then premise.id throws "string indices must be integers". If I fix this, premise.id throws: "list indices must be integers, not str" ... oO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to #pyramid in the IRC i got the first hint, which is mentioned in the comment. But..never ever name a key 'value' or 'values'!